# OpenCV 2.4.6 for Android shows errors

Tags: android, opencv

I am trying to run HelloCV on Android and have been following the doc for OpenCV on Android . Unfortunately I stumbled across this error when I used OpenCV 2.4.6.

Under cleaning all projects , I got theses errors:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV Library - @OPENCV_VERSION@'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV Sample - 15 puzzle'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV Sample - color-blob-detection'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV Sample - face-detection'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV Sample - image-manipulations'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV Sample - native-activity'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV Tutorial 1 - Camera Preview'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV Tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV Tutorial 3 - Camera Control'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV_JavaAPI_Tests'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

And under building workspace I got these errors;

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV Library - @OPENCV_VERSION@'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV Sample - 15 puzzle'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV Sample - color-blob-detection'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV Sample - face-detection'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV Sample - image-manipulations'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV Sample - native-activity'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV Tutorial 1 - Camera Preview'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV Tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV Tutorial 3 - Camera Control'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'OpenCV_JavaAPI_Tests'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Should I try to work with another version of OpenCV , or there are some inherent config problem in my environment . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i think you did not follow the tutorial closely. Focus on the android and opencv part.   [tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/table_of_content_introduction/table_of_content_introduction.html#table-of-content-introduction)